# react-native run-android command is failing, Err: Unable to process daemon

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am stuck since a long time with this error,
when I try hitting react-native run-android, my build is failing, below is the error:

```
react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 2263 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 52 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 53 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u282-b08\bin\java.exe -Xmx4096m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Parentlane\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.8-bin\1jblhjyydfkclfzx1agp92nyl\gradle-6.8\lib\gradle-launcher-6.8.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.8
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to allocate 131072KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 4194304KB heap.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Stuck since a long time now, have got no idea how to fix this, kindly help

Comment: did you solve the problem?